# How to get facebook posts with comments and likes count of a trending topics?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-fql

I want to retrieve trending topics from Facebook, using API call, with information like posts related to trending topics, likes and comments of a post. Is there any facebook API which can do this ?

Comment: There is no API to get trending topics

Comment: Thanks for reply.